# How to add article image to module mod_article_categories?

Tags: module, articles, template-override, module-display

I am using Articles - Categories module in my Joomla website (my custom template) and it works great, meaning that it lists all articles with intro text from the categories I want.

But it does not show the **intro-image** of these articles although I defined them in each article "**Image and links**" tab. Is there a way to show intro images?

I suppose that I need to do some template overriding.

You can see it here:

http://nolimitsbl.com/teimc/index.php/l ... tovarivaci

I just want to mention that bold black titles are categories titles and bellow them are listed articles with intro texts.

Need help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yep, I would also do the template override.

Fetch the file `components/com_content/views/categories/tmpl/default_items.php` and copy it to `<your_template>/html/com_content/categories/default_items.php`. (I am not totally sure about the correct name, see the Joomla docs about this)

Now you can edit it. In the file `components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php` I found `<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>`, this could perhaps make the deal.

Nice big machines, BTW. :)

Comment: Solved!
I put the code:

<?php
$images = json_decode($item->images);
?>
<img class="image_intro" src="<?php echo $images->image_intro; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images->image_intro_alt; ?>"/>

after the following code in my overriding file of the joomla core file
modules/mod_articles_categories/tmpl/default.php

and intro images of articles shown up in module Articles-Categories listing.

If anyone has other solutions, come on shoot...

Answer (score 3):

Solved! I put the code:

`<?php $images = json_decode($item->images); ?>
   <img class="image_intro" src="<?php echo $images->image_intro; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images->image_intro_alt; ?>"/>`

after the following code in my overriding file of the joomla core file:

> modules/mod_articles_categories/tmpl/default.php

```
* @subpackage  mod_articles_category
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

?>
<ul class="category-module<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
    <?php if ($grouped) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($list as $group_name => $group) : ?>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($group as $item) : ?>    
                    <li>
```

and intro images of articles shown up in module Articles-Categories listing. If anyone has other solutions, come on shoot...

Answer (score 0):

Path should actually be: modules/mod_articles_category/tmpl/default.php

One more important suggestion, place the changed files in your own template in /[yourTemplateName]/html/mod_articles_category/default.php

This way the file will not be removed when upgrading Joomla.