# Display images for joomla related items module

Tags: joomla-3.x

I setup the native joomla module to display related items in articles, but by default only the title of the article displays.
I want the article image and if possible the article rating to be displayed.

I have tried the code below which works for displaying article image in other modules but to no success.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo json_decode($item->images)->image_intro; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->title; ?>"/>
```

I will appreciate your kind assistance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you have a Look at [How to add article image to module mod_article_categories?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10880/how-to-add-article-image-to-module-mod-article-categories)?

Maybe this helps also on Module_related.

Comment: Thanks Franz for your suggestion. The code you suggested is the same i already tried as seen in my question.

Comment: Sorry, i'm no Developer so i looked at Topic and Question, not on (for me unreadable) Code.